# Stored Procedure, find the duplicate file name and return the value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have logic to verify whether the filename is unique or not. For this I need to pass the parameter 'FileName'

Logic:

```
SELECT value = COUNT(*)  
FROM  ProcessingLog
WHERE ProcessingOutcome IN (1,2)  
AND FileName = [FileName] 

IF value <> 0 THEN  
RETURN ErrorID 2
```

Default: n/a 
Error Code: 2: E002: Source File has been previously processed (duplicate Source File)  
Output Target: ProcessingLog.ErrorID  
Output Format: int

I wrote a query like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[xx]    
    @FileName int = NULL OUTPUT    
AS
BEGIN       
    DECLARE @V_FileName VARCHAR(225);

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT FileName, count(*)
    FROM  PbrcServiceProcessingLog  
    WHERE ProcessingOutcome IN (1,2)  
          AND SourceFileName = @SourceFileName 
    GROUP BY SourceFileName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 0

    IF count !=0 THEN  RETURN ErrorID 2     
END
```

How can I pass the errorID into the processing ?

Comment: So to clarify, you want to pass **in** a filename and return a value to indicate whether it exists or not?

Comment: Yes. 0 means is the new filename and value 2 means there is a duplicate file. Thx

Comment: @song josh - What issue you are facing? I can see couple of issues in your query/procedure. Why you have taken '@FileName' as the Output parameter? You have used the '@SourceFileName' parameter in your query but not declare/passed in your procedure '@SourceFileName'. You have used FileName in select but grouping is done on SourceFileName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do what you require.

1. Your parameter name does not need to be an `output`
2. Your parameter name does need to match the parameter used in the query.
3. A simple `exists` is all that is required in this case - no counting needed.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[xx]    
    @FileName int = NULL
AS
BEGIN       
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if exists (
        SELECT 1
        FROM PbrcServiceProcessingLog  
        WHERE ProcessingOutcome IN (1,2) AND SourceFileName = @FileName 
    )
      return 2
    else
      return 0;
END
```

And to insert into a table

```
declare @FileName nvarchar(256) = 'MyTestFileName.txt', @Result int;

exec @Result = dbo.xx @FileName;

insert into ProcessingLog (ErrorId, FileName)
select @Result, @FileName
where @Result = 2;
```

Note: This doesn't really require a Stored Procedure, if you want to reuse this query in multiple places put it in an Inline Table Valued Function e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[xx]
(    
  @FileName int = NULL
)
returns table
return
  select case when exists (
    SELECT 1
    FROM PbrcServiceProcessingLog  
    WHERE ProcessingOutcome IN (1,2) AND SourceFileName = @FileName 
  )
  then 2 else 0 end FileExists;
```

Then for a single value use as:

```
select FileExists from dbo.xx(@FileName);
```

Or to call against a column in a table, use as:

```
select Filename
  , (select FileExists from dbo.xx(FileName)) FileExists
from MyTable;
```

And to insert into a table

```
insert into ProcessingLog (ErrorId, FileName)
select ErrorId, @FileName
from (
    select FileExists from dbo.xx(@FileName)
) x
where x.FileExists = 2;
```

Comment: as it is returning only scalar value, we dont need table valued UDF. Scallar UDF would suffice, I think.

Comment: @VenkataramanR scalar functions have horrible performance, whereas inline table valued functions perform quite well (mostly).

Comment: agreed. but, here as we just checking for fileexistance ,inline table valued function is kind of overkill, I think.

Comment: What if there is a duplicate file, so the output is 2, how can I put the value 2 with the filename into ErrorID column, filename column of my output target table 'ProcessingLog'. Many Thanks

Comment: @VenkataramanR overkill? Its the same number of lines to define, in principle I always use a ITVF to avoid any future performance issues. Its my default function type. I avoid scalar function at all costs - and recommend others do the same. The only times I would recommend a scalar function is if for some reason the ITVF performs badly - which can happen.